# Multiple BeforeBuild targets

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I want to create two distinct nuget packages in order to make some prebuild stuff on my project. The custom target files associated to the NuGet packages have both a BeforeBuild Target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command='...' />
</Target>
```

I noticed that the BeforeBuild target get executed just once, this sounds correct but in my scenario, where I want two pre build steps added by packages, how the problem could be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define multiple differently named target that hook into the build phase (using the `BeforeTargets` hook) and not overwrite the `BeforeBuild` target:

```
<Target Name="MyCustomTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command='...' />
</Target>
```

Refer to the [Target build order documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) for more details on the execution order.